# Is it possible to serialize a classname similar to a property

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.0

I understand I can use  code similar to the below to change the property name from Name to name when it is serialized but I also want to change the object name when it is serialized and returned using return something like Ok(myobj);

But, is it possible to do something similar for the class as below so it is serialized as person and not Person. I've looked at JsonObject but can't see anything on there.

```cs
[JsonObject(PropertyName="person")]
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your class name to start with a lowercase letter, you can do this:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class Person
{

}
```

This would set the first letter of your class name to lowercase since it uses `CamelCaseNamingStategy`, you can also create your own custom naming strategy to fit your needs, implementation of existing naming stategies can be found here: (https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization)

Answer (score 0):

You will need another wrapper object to have like that. You can use:

```
return Ok(new{
  Person = myobj
});
```